# How to avoid double network requesting per one fetch in React 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-18

Trying to make a memory card game by guide with React 18 and Pexels API I've meet some problem.

Trying to fetch data from API somehow my app send double network request per "mounting". Spent several hours trying to fix it with zero result. Also

```
useEffect(() => {
// some code
}, [])
```

can't solve my problem.

Code below

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {App} from './App';

import './styles/index.scss';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Background} from './components/Background/Background';
import {useGetImages} from "./utils/hooks/useGetImages";

export const App = () => {
    const images = useGetImages();

    console.log({images})

    return (
        <>
            <Background/>
            <h1>Memory Game</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

**useGetImages.js** // custom hook

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {BASE_URL} from "../constants/constants";

const getRandomPage = () => Math.round(Math.random() * (60 - 1) +1);

export const useGetImages = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    const buildUrl = () => {
        let url = new URL(BASE_URL);

        url.search = new URLSearchParams({
            query: 'nature',
            orientation: 'square',
            size: 'small',
            per_page: 2,
            page: getRandomPage(),
        });

        return url;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPics = () => {
            fetch(buildUrl(), {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_KEY,
                },
            })
                .then(data => data.json())
                .then(data => setImages(data.photos));
        };

        fetchPics();
    },[]);

    return images;
};
```

**base url just in case**

```
export const BASE_URL = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/search';
```

P.S.  component do not contain any logic just wierdo animations.

P.S.S. Can't share api key in terms of Pexels rules and laws.

Help me pls...

Comment: Have you checked if your useEffect was triggered twice? Maybe console.log() inside useEffect, or did you see this only in the network tab?

Comment: @YevhenKazmirchuk honestly I wasn't even close to try console log inside useEffect, was only cheacking network tab, will try for sure, ty. Doubled request was before i tried to add useEffect as well, but I can't believe the fetch itself can be a bugged problem.